# How to reassign the drive letter of a network share?

Tags: windows, remapping, network-drive, drive-letter

I've mapped a network drive to `\\server\shared` to the drive letter `E:`. To make it appear at the end of the drive list under *My PC* in Explorer's navigation pane I want to change the drive letter to `X:`.

How can I do that quickly without disconnecting the old network drive and mapping a new one?
Is there a fast way, gladly also in the command line, like there is for removable drives in `diskmgmt.msc`?

[image: Change Drive Letter and Paths]

I've renamed the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Network\E` key to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Network\X`,
but this only lead to the `net use` output

```
Status       Lokal     Remote                    Netzwerk
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK           E:        \\server\share            Microsoft Windows Network
Nicht verfgb X:        \\server\share            Microsoft Windows Network
```

Comment: It would be simpler to delete and recreate the share.

Comment: Thank You, I've done that. It bogged me and I asked this question for shortcuts.

Comment: I think you have found the shortcut. Modifying the registry is not the safest solution.

Comment: @cachius why exactly don't you want to "disconnect the old network drive"? Just to save time?

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the registry with incomplete knowledge is unsafe.
It's better to use regular Windows mechanisms.

The simplest method is to delete and recreate the network share.

For reference materials, see for example
[How to Delete Network Share Windows OS](https://www.action1.com/how-to-delete-network-share-windows-operating-systems/)

Comment: I don't agree with the statement _Modifying the registry is unsafe_. It depends a lot on what you're editing. Some keys may be critical, others certainly aren't. In this case I agree with you, as it doesn't achieve the desired result and has unwanted side effects.

Comment: I meant the modifications of the kind you did, not all of them. I changed the answer to "modifying the registry with incomplete knowledge".

Comment: @harrymc Your advice is sound, just a small but important addition: "Modifying the registry with incomplete knowledge" would be called "reverse engineering" and lots of users do it. It's only unsafe if you didn't take the necessary precautions like backups, etc.

Comment: @Albin: Most users find that information on the web in unverified sources, and many get into trouble this way.

Comment: @harrymc I know, that's why I wrote "your advice is sound"